# neo4j case statement in Foreach

Tags: foreach, neo4j, case

whats the most efficient way to write this query. The problem. I have a set of 3500 names of boys and girls who play basketball. I want to assing a relationship to them as to they belong_to toddlers, youth, teenagers based on their age group.

I am unable to do a case statement inside a foreach.

```
Match(b:BoysandGirls)
UNWIND (b.name) as namelist
FOREACH (fullname in namelist | 
  MERGE(b1:BoysandGirls {name:fullname})
  CASE WHEN b1.age < 6 THEN
       MERGE(t1:KidsType {group:"Toddler"})  // this groups already exist
       MERGE(b1)-[BELONGS_TO]->(t1)
   END
)
```

// i have more groups   like youth and teenager... but not sure
I get an error Invalid input ... expected 1/L..  at CASE statement.
what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

`FOREACH` only permits mutating operations, but `CASE` is not a mutating operation (and `CASE` also cannot contain match/mutating operations). Aside from those issues, I think you are also confused about what `UNWIND` does -- you probably meant `COLLECT` instead. But I don't think you need to use `COLLECT` and `FOREACH` at all (since they basically cancel each other out).

This much simpler query might be all you need:

```
MATCH (bg:BoysandGirls)
WHERE bg.age < 6
MATCH (t:KidsType {group:"Toddler"})
MERGE (bg)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t);
```

It finds all `BoysandGirls` younger than 6 and ensures that they are related (via the `BELONGS_TO` relationship type -- note the required preceding colon) to the "Toddler" `KidsType`.

Comment: @ClickAway Another thing to consider, if the only purpose of this is to categorize nodes (if there are no other properties on :KidsType nodes, and you don't plan on using those nodes for any other reason), you could add additional labels on your nodes (:Toddler, :Youth, :Teenager). Neo4j allows multi-labeled nodes, and you'll be able to match using these labels for quick queries on age groups.